# Laravel Livewire default rules taking precedence over explicitly defined rules

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel v10.25.2 and Livewire v3.0.5.

I am trying to use the File Uploads in my component:

```
class CaseNew extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
.../
```

I am trying to validate the file input with custom rules applied on the component property:

```
public function updatedAttachments()
    {
        $this->resetValidation();
        $this->validate([
            'attachments.*' => 'file|array:5|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif,zip,pdf,docx,xlsx,txt,heic|max:11000'
        ]);
    }
```

I have also tried the same approach like this:

```
#[Rule(['attachments.*' => 'file|max:11000|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif,zip,pdf,docx,xlsx,txt,heic'])]
public $attachments = [];
```

However, when I try to test it and attach a file that is bigger than 11000 KB, I get the error in my blade that the file size exceeds 12288 KB, which is Livewire's default size. It seems no matter which way I try to do this, I get the same error matching the default value, not the value I specify in my rules.

Now I can set the default value in my `config/livewire.php` file, but shouldn't setting the rule like above override that? If I happen to implement file upload in different parts of my site, that have their own requirements, the general rules cannot cover them all in that case. Am I doing something wrong in my process or missing something else?

Comment: What about `#[Rule('file|max:11000|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif,zip,pdf,docx,xlsx,txt,heic')]`

Comment: I actually had it arranged in that order to begin with, and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: It's not just re-arrange, compare with your Rule attribute

Comment: Oh I see the difference, totally overlooked it. I did try that, and I get the same result. It goes off of the default value set in the `config/livewire.php` file.